# Algorithm to optimize a team formation based on player rating and power

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I want to create an algorithm for a hypothetical game where you can create as many groups as desired with a given list of players.
Suppose I have a list of players, where every player is represented by their rating.

[Given The following matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK96w.png)

The numbers in yellow correspond to the amount of players in any given group.

The numbers in white correspond to the score that each player in the group is contributing.

The numbers in orange correspond to the rating threshold needed for the corresponding score.

For example, if I have a group of players of rating [50, 100], using the matrix it can be determined that they are each generating a score of 26.45, since the total rating is 150 and there are two players in that group. The total score in that team is 52.90.

Ideally the algorithm would return the groups that yield to the best score, with the constraints that I can make as many groups as wanted, and not all players need to be put in a group.

What would be a good way to get started or solve this algorithm?

Comment: Probably a MIP solver, but how many players are we talking about?

Comment: About 15-20 players

Answer (score 0):

I'd reduce this problem to weighted set packing and use a mixed integer program (MIP) solver library such as [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip).

For every subset S of players that can form a group, we have a variable x(S) that is 1 if we choose the subset and 0 otherwise. We let the score of the subset be score(S), so that the objective is to maximize the sum over S of score(S) x(S). We have a constraint for each player p: the sum over all S containing p of x(S) is at most 1.

For example, with three players with all nonempty subsets as possible groups, we would get

```
maximize score({1}) x({1}) + score({2}) x({2}) + score({3}) x({3}) +
score({1,2}) x({1,2}) + score({1,3}) x({1,3}) + score({2,3}) x({2,3}) +
score({1,2,3}) x({1,2,3})

subject to

x({1}) + x({1,2}) + x({1,3}) + x({1,2,3}) <= 1
x({2}) + x({1,2}) + x({2,3}) + x({1,2,3}) <= 1
x({3}) + x({1,3}) + x({2,3}) + x({1,2,3}) <= 1

x({1}), ..., x({1,2,3}) in {0, 1}
```

Unless the scores are close to linear, modern MIP solvers on modern hardware should be able to scale to 20 players. If not, there are more complicated techniques.